# Tag excerpts do not fit on tags page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

On the [tags page](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/tags), in some long enough tag excerpts, the text overflows a bit:

[image]

**Edit:** this also applies to some [meta site tags](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/tags).

Comment: Yeah, we were planning to shorten/alter the excerpts a bit once the pro-tem mods get elected. Other than that the SE team would have to modify their code, which I'm not sure is a priority for them.

Answer (score 2):

The tag listing is intended to show only a *portion* of the excerpt as allowed by space allotted (akin to the text excerpts [on this 'Questions' page](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions)). To see the rest of the excerpt, you can hover over it, or click through to the tag entry to see the entire contents.

Comment: Yeah, but I think then the excerpt text itself should be shortened by the page so that it fits (also maybe add `...` to the end, like on the questions page you linked to) and displayed. Right now it looks weird because you can still see tiny parts of the characters and select them.